# Tips on basic electricity and magnetism books

Tags: electromagnetism, resource-recommendations, education

I would like to study basic electricity and magnetism with a book with a good mathematical language (e.g. to calculate the thing with gauss law the book explain the importance of parametrization, coordinate change inside integral and so on...)

Answer (score 0):

Try 'Introduction to Electrodynamics' by David Griffiths. The first chapter gives an intuitive explanation of the mathematical concepts used. Furthermore, there are lots of examples, and many good exercises.